# Inverter valor 0 ou 1 em uma coluna

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

Tenho uma tabela que tem inúmeros registros e uma coluna chamada `posição`.

Ela só recebe o valor 0 para bloqueado e 1 para liberado.

Ai agora com uma mudança preciso inverter estes valores, onde esta 0 tem que ser 1 e onde esta 1 tem que ser 0.

Como eu faço isto no `update` do MySQL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isto, provavelmente, é o que precisa:

```
UPDATE Pedidos SET posicao = 1 - posicao;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Update/InvertValue.sql).

Comment: Então eu não sei como fazer este update. A tabela se chama Pedidos e a coluna em questão se chama posicao como eu falei acima. Nesta coluna so aceita 0 e 1 nos valores eu preciso rodar um update que inverta eles. Onde for posicao=1 tem que ficar posicao=0 e onde for posicao=0 tem que ficar posicao=1. Espero ter conseguido explicar melhor.

Comment: @JoaoNivaldo mas é exatamente o que esta na resposta, não?

Comment: @JoaoNivaldo, a resposta está correta. Quando `posicao` for igual a 0, o update vai fazer a conta `1 - 0` que é igual a 1 (inverteu de 0 para 1). Se `posicao` for igual a 1, o update vai fazer a conta `1 - 1` que é igual a 0 (inverteu de 1 para 0).

Comment: Deu certinho. É que a primeira vez que eu vi estava escrito tabela onde apareceu posição por isto eu não entendi. Ai depois que eu tinha respondido apareceu a sua edição. Muito obrigado